# Preserving state of UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I've seen many conflicting answers that seem to be situation dependent, but I haven't figured out one that works for me. I'm building a tabbed application in Storyboard, and I want to save the state of a view controller inside one tab that lives inside a navigation controller. It has dynamically created objects (labels and pictures) that I want to preserve when the app is shut down.

Thus far, I have the following in AppDelegate.m:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {
return YES; }
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {
return YES; }
```

and in my viewController.m file:

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
[coder encodeObject:self.view forKey:@"view"];
[super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder]; }

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
self.view = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"view"];
[super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder]; }
```

I've also assigned RestorationID's to UITabBarController, the navigation controller, and the view controller in question.

Right now, if I minimize and restore, data is preserved, but if I stop and restart using xcode, it's lost. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run an app, push the Home button twice to go to the app switcher, swipe your app away to close it and run it by clicking the icon on home screen (not from Xcode!). Is now everything ok?

I suppose when you run your app from Xcode it not just relaunches it, but reinstalls it, so that is not exactly what you need.

Comment: running from xcode reinstalls it? I didn't realize that, since the app doesn't disappear from the simulator.

I tried dismissing it and relaunching it within the simulator; it was preserved, but strangely, after a few seconds the preserved state disappeared. Is this just an xcode bug? Were you referring to actually testing it on a device?

Comment: Well, according to WWDC2013 presentation "What’s New in State Restoration" it's sufficient for app to restore after being closed, not being rebuild to say that it supports state restoration. At least that's how it was demonstrated.